# Python rule of for statement

Tags: python, for-loop

I just began learning Python. So I am a beginner. I have a question about "for statement." I think I still don't know the rule of it.
Please see below.

example:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []

def forStatement():
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(5, 7):
            list2.append(j)
        list1.append(list2)
    return list1
```

The result I am looking for is;

```
[[5, 6], [5, 6], [5, 6]]
```

But when I run that code, it turns out like this.

```
[[5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6], [5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6], [5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6]]
```

Can anyone help me? How can I get that result?
Thank you so much.

Comment: This a FAQ of Python, I believe there is a duplicate...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 3):

You are almost correct, the only problem with your code is that you keep adding elements to `list2`. Instead, you should create a new list every time:

```
list1 = []

for i in range(3):
    list2 = []
    for j in range(5, 7):
        list2.append(j)
    list1.append(list2)
```

Comment: If my answer helped solve your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are appending in the loop, where you want to reset list2 each iteration of i

```
list1 = []

for i in range(3):
    list2 = []
    for j in range(5, 7):
        list2.append(j)
    list1.append(list2)

>>> print list1
[[5, 6], [5, 6], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code, `list1` is a container object which takes references to an object to which `list2` is bound. (Usually, such a object is mentioned as `list2` for brevity.) After the execution of the code, `list1` finally contains three elements (i.e. references to `list2`) and `list2` obviously contains triple (outer loop executed 3 times) consecutive 5, 6 (every execution of inner loop append 5 and 6 to `list2`).

The following code should be what you expect:

```
list1 = []

list2 = None

for i in range(3):
    list2 = [] # To create a new empty list object and let it bound to the variable list2 every outer loop.
    for j in range(5, 7):
        list2.append(j)
    list1.append(list2)
```

In this code, after the execution, `list1` contains three elements that are distinct objects. But they were all bound to the variable `list2` in the past.